# I'm trying to write the first 47 Fibonacci numbers to a disk file. What should I fix?

Tags: assembly, fibonacci, irvine32

```
; This program will store the first 47 Fibonacci numbers in an array of doublewords and write the doubleword array to a disk file

include Irvine32.inc

FibCount = 45

.data

    fileName BYTE "Fib47", 0    ; Creates file name
    FibArray DWORD ?            ; Initializes DWORD array to store fibonacci numbers

.code

main PROC

    mov ecx, FibCount
    mov esi, OFFSET FibArray
    call CreateOutputFile
    call computeFibonacciNumbers
    call WriteToFile

    exit
main ENDP

;-----------------------------------------------
; Computes Fibonacci numbers (type DWORD) and stores them in an array
; Receives: ECX = count of Fibonacci numbers
;           ESI = offset of array of Fibonacci numbers
; Returns: nothing
;----------------------------------------------

computeFibonacciNumbers PROC

    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 1

L1:
    cmp ecx, 0
    jbe L2
    add eax, ebx
    mov edx, eax
    mov FibArray, edx
    mov ebx, eax
    mov edx, ebx
    loop L1

L2:
    ret

computeFibonacciNumbers ENDP

END main
```

Comment: For starters, you should explain in your question what it is that's not working, in as much detail as possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
mov ecx, FibCount
mov esi, OFFSET FibArray
call CreateOutputFile
call computeFibonacciNumbers
```

Why do you call *CreateOutputFile* **between** the setup of the arguments for *computeFibonacciNumbers* and the actual calling of *computeFibonacciNumbers*? Highly illogical and prone to errors.

```
FibArray DWORD ?            ; Initializes DWORD array to store fibonacci numbers
```

Your setup of *FibArray* just prepares room for 1 dword. If you want room for an array of 47 elements then write:

```
FibArray DWORD 47 dup(?)
```

- The *computeFibonacciNumbers* procedure has ESI for an argument, yet you don't use it anywhere.
- In this procedure you're moving all the values on top of each other. Better write `mov [esi],edx` `add esi,4`
- You can savely move the `cmp ecx,0` `jbe L2` before the loop. You need not retest this condition.
- You loop does not require the use of EDX at all.